# Add a unique constraint over muliple reference columns

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, jpa, unique-constraint

Hello i want to add a unique constraint over two referenced columns:

```
@Entity()
@Table(uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = { "ast", "tfs" }))
public class N extends UUID {

@ManyToOne(optional = false)
@JoinColumn(name = "ast")
private A ast;

@ManyToOne(optional = false)
@JoinColumn(name = "tfs")
private T tfs;
```

In Class UUID is logic for generating a Primary ID.

Hibernate generates 3 Constraint, PK, 2 Secondary Keys.. but i am expecting 4 Constraints. 
Does someone have a idea ?

Edit:

```
@Entity
public class A extends UUID implements Serializable {

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "ast")
private List<N> nutz;
```

and

```
@Entity
public class T extends UUID implements Serializable {

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "tfs")
private List<N> nutz;
```

Comment: I would expect in your case only two constraints: the PK constraint and the UniqueConstraint (over two fields). What are the constraints of Hibernate and what are the constraints that you expect?

Comment: Then i have no reference to the other entitys. At the moment there are 1PrimaryKey(uuid) 2SecondaryKey(to ast and to tfs) Constraints. I expect 1PrimaryKey 2SecondaryKey plus 1Uniqe(ast,tfs) constraint.

Comment: Of course, I didn't count the Foreign Key constraints. Are you sure you do not have multiple combinations `{"ast", "tfs"}` in your table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works if I set:

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop" />
```

instead of

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
```

It seems Hibernate only creates constaints if the whole database is created and not when it creates the table! Confusing.  [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2944112/unique-constraint-not-created-in-jpa?rq=1)

Comment: This is a Bug, fixed in 4.2.1 see https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-8092