# @UniqueConstraint requires alter table in MariaDB if table already existed before with no constraints?

Tags: spring, hibernate, mariadb, unique-constraint

I apologize if I repeat the question, but I did not find a similar one.

I have added a unique constraint on an already existent table. We use MariaDB.

I have used the annotation:

```
@Table(uniqueConstraints={@UniqueConstraint(name="autonomy_name_energyType", columnNames={"autonomy","name","energyType"})})
```

The unit tests pass, but in the DB I am still allowed to create duplicates.

Do I need an ALTER table too? By checking the table I can see there are no constraints added to it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained in these SO posts :

- [Unique constraint not created in JPA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2944112/unique-constraint-not-created-in-jpa)
- [@Column(unique=true) does not seem to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3496028/columnunique-true-does-not-seem-to-work/3498242#3498242)

An explicit alter table query is needed for ur constaints to take effect on the db level.

As an extra info, it would have worked if the table was being re-created via JPA. see :
[Add a unique constraint over muliple reference columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20194314/add-a-unique-constraint-over-muliple-reference-columns?noredirect=1&lq=1)